# How to add an icon over a CircleAvatar flutter

Tags: flutter

I wanna know how to add an icon like online icon over a CircleAvatar.

I've wrote this code but dont know what to do...

```
 ...
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff00A3FF),
    radius: 35.0,
    backgroundImage:
    AssetImage("assets/photos/photo-1.jpg"),
), 
SizedBox(height: 7.0),
Text(
     "Michael",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,: FontWeight.w700),
)
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is a Stack widget. Stack widgets allow you to place widgets on top of widgets (meaning order is crucial).

Here I modified your CircleAvatar to add a little green "online" indicator. Make sure to adjust the size and such to fit your needs.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff00A3FF),
      backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/photos/photo-1.jpg"),
      radius: 35.0,
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.white
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90.0),
        color: Colors.green
        )
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with nested circle avatars like this:

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 58,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/photos/photo-1.jpg"),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 18,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 16,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green
          )
        )
      )
    ]
  )
);
```

The result is like this:

[image]

If you want to add an icon, you can do like this

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 58,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/photos/photo-1.jpg"),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 18,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: Icon(Icons.camera) // change this children 
        )
      )
    ]
  )
);
```

and the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a circleAvatar in a circleAvatar.
just use backgroundImage property of the CircleAvatar. like this;

```
NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl)
```

more on that:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html